# How to create and serve map tiles?

Tags: leaflet, tiles, generate-tiles

I have shapefile which is too large to be served as vector. Also, I need it only as background tile, not as layer with attributes.

I thought of creating tiles in MapTiler as I already bought it. I see MapTiles accepts raster input. Where should I create rasters from shapefile? I need it for only 3-4 zoom levels. What would be next step? I have a very good server, should I uploaded it to my server? Should I process it via Geoserver as WMS? What would be best approach if I need it in Leaflet application?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/

Comment: I know how to publish shapefile on Geoserver, as wms, wfs etc. I asked what would be best process to publish it on my server. And how to generate tiles from shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use QGIS software and its plugin called Qtiles to convert your shapefile into tiles. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/. Another way for generating tiles is to use TileMill by exporting shapefile.